# How to ensure date is stored from Java to SQLServer to millisecond resolution?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, datetime

We are using Hibernate.

In Java, the object is java.util.Date.
In SQLServer, the column is datetime2(7).

When we store this object in SQLServer database and later retrieve it, this object is not having same value in millisecond resolution.

For example, from Java: `Dec 01 2016 15:50.453` 
When it comes back from the database: `Dec 01 2016 15:50.455`

So, we are encountering scenarios where the equals() is failing due to this design aspect of SQLServer.

Is there something missing in Hibernate dialect, like for example: registering column types.

Or should I define some conversion, so that I get the correct value, which I had saved.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bad design.  You can't guarantee any such thing.

Instead of creating a value on the Java side and passing it to SQL Server, why not call `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on the database server and save that?

It's not clear to me from your description where the timestamp lives on the Java side.  Is it in the Java object itself?  Is that the value that you INSERT into the database?  You're saying that the value from the object is off two 2 milliseconds when you persist it in SQL Server?

I would suggest that your design would be better off not depending on timestamps being accurate to a millisecond.

I'll point out that you have no hope whatsoever of changing any design aspect of SQL Server or Java.

Perhaps it'd be easier to answer if you could post more requirements that would clarify why you depend on the timestamp.

Comment: no. current timestamp is not the only usecase. in application runtime, we might save date in some object and persist in database at later point of time..

Comment: You're asking for trouble comparing timestamps.  But I can't tell without more detail what I'd recommend for an alternative.  Usually I depend on a GUID that ties all objects to a particular session.  I can create that and reliably retrieve it for all associated data.